# Video disappearing from RTSP stream

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming

I've been trying to stream a video using VLC on my computer (Ubuntu 19.04) and watch the stream on the VLC for FireTV app. Maddeningly, it worked a few times, but now VLC is consistently playing the audio from the stream without the video - although the issue goes away if I try playing back the stream on the same computer. I'd appreciate any help with debugging this.

Here are two command lines, with and without transcoding respectively, that I've tried based on [a tutorial](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#RTSP_live_streaming).

```
vlc -vvv $HOME/video.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/video}'
vlc -vvv $HOME/video.mp4 --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/video}'
```

Thanks in advance. This question is cross-posted from the VideoLAN forums, where they generally want to see some VLC version information - here's mine:

```
VLC media player 3.0.7.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.7.1-0-gf3940db4af)
VLC version 3.0.7.1 Vetinari (3.0.7.1-0-gf3940db4af)
Compiled by buildd on lcy01-amd64-019.buildd (Jul 24 2019 14:40:43)
Compiler: gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
```